# Make div clicked with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im mobile optimizing a website. There is a page with different packages you can select by clicking before proceeding to the next page. By default package 1 is selected but im hiding this option on mobile. This creates an issue if you dont select another option and proceed as you have unknowingly selected an package that you cant see.

To get around this I want to make another (visible) package selected by default. I dont want to edit the original javascript or the back end, I would much rather my code was separate.

Ive tried the code below to use jQuery to 'click' the option as a user would. Tt works in the demo but not on the actual site. Ive tried running it after a delay and in both dom read and window load. Im afraid I cant publish the site or make the actual code visible.

```
$('div').click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LZWjs/3/

Comment: What kind of element is the option?

Comment: if you right click on the element you have and paste the css code you have by default on the element we can see iff there is something overriding it in css inheritance

Comment: Hard to debug without the actual code. It's supposed to work =\.

Comment: Show us your code so we can help! This could be a selector specificity thing or the click event could be overridden or unbound at some point.

Comment: Your fiddle is good (works) so we need more information to assit you at all.

Comment: @Explosion Pills the element is a link but the href is javascript.

Comment: @Dominic Green, why would the CSS make a difference? By 'selected' I mean something that the site's existing javascript understands, not a css pseudo class.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss I know im not being very helpful but its impossible for me to show the code. Are there any areas for suggestion I should look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use custom event to catch the click event. just trigger the click

```
$(document).trigger('customClick');
```

then catch the event:

```
$(document).on('customClick', function () {
     // do whatever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below:

```
$('div').click();
```

will execute **click** event on every `div` so this is probably not what you want to do, it will probably call your selection code multiple times and god knows what else. In order to simulate selection from user you need to give your `div` an **ID** and to `trigger` click on it e.g.

```
$('#ID').click();
```

If this does not solves your problem you can always insert some console.logs or alerts in your pages selection mechanism so you can track witch events are triggered. This is as far as i can help you if you are unwilling to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile you can skip rendering the first irrelevant option, then initialize the form and make the first available option selected. In case of a radio button control it would be:

```
$("ul.optionsList input.anOption:first").attr("checked", true)
```

...presuming that `ul.optionsList` is the options container, and `anOption` is a class name for the radio element.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your approach.

First, as Ivan said, `$('div').click();` will cause the click event to be raised on every single `<div>` in your page, which is not what you want. I've updated your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LZWjs/4/) to demonstrate this. Ivan is correct in suggesting that you use an ID to specifically select which package you want to have clicked. For example:

```
<div id="package1">Hidden</div>
<div id="package2">Pick me</div>
<div id="package3">Another package</div>

<script>$('#package2').click();</script>
```

Alternatively, you could use whatever method your Javascript uses to tell the difference between the various packages to determine which one to select, be it CSS classes, HTML5 *data-* attributes, etc.

---

Second, how are you hiding the first selected package? Something similar to `$('.selected').hide();` perhaps? Why not remove the first package from the DOM entirely, and then fire a click event at the new "first" package? For example:

```
$('.selected').remove();
$('.packages').first().click();
```

---

Third, you commented *"the element is a link but the href is javascript."* Why are you firing the *click* event on `<div>` then? By the sound of it, you should be targeting the `<a>` elements instead.

---

Fourth, jQuery's `click()` function only triggers the *click* **event**. This is not the same as *"use jQuery to 'click' the option as a user would."* If all your Javascript is in the `<a>` *href* attribute, it will only fire when the user clicks on it manually, not when the *click* event is triggered. I've put together an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bCg8A/) to highlight the difference.